# DROP Oracle queue

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to drop the queue using following command:

```
 EXECUTE DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE (queue_name => 'ORDVAL_QUEUE');
```

It is working fine but i want to put a check if queue does not exist and i execute above command thn it should not throw an error or exception.
I m using this but din't got my target :

```
 BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE (queue_name => "ORDVAL_QUEUE")';
  EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  null;
  END;
```

It executes fine but does not drop queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used queues before, but this should help:

1. Add a `BEGIN` and `END` to the execute immediate, to use dynamic PL/SQL instead of dynamic SQL.
2. Use two single quotes instead of a double quote.
3. Catch specific exceptions when possible, avoid `OTHERS`.  This was catching and ignoring unexpected exceptions.
4. Not shown below, but perhaps it would be better to check for the existence of the queue in `ALL_QUEUES` instead?

```
    DECLARE
        QUEUE_DOES_NOT_EXIST EXCEPTION;
        PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(QUEUE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -24010);
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
            'BEGIN DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE (queue_name => ''ORDVAL_QUEUE''); END;';
        EXCEPTION WHEN queue_does_not_exist then
            dbms_output.put_line('Test to see if exception was thrown');
    END;
    /
```

Comment: I m able to drop the queue using following command without error:BEGIN
   DBMS_AQADM.DROP_QUEUE (queue_name => 'AV_QUEUE');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      null;
END;

Comment: That's even better if you can remove an execute immediate.  But you may still want to use a more specific exception handler, unless you really don't care about any potential errors.